# LINQ lambda with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to convert this LINQ statement into a `Lambda` expression.

```
totalTickets = (from parent in context.EventParentSponsors
    join sponsor in context.EventSponsors
    on parent.EventSponsorId equals sponsor.EventSponsorId
    where parent.ParentSponsorID == parentId
    select sponsor.InvitationCount).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is what I have so far:

```
totalTickets = context.EventParentSponsors
    .Join(context.EventSponsors, 
        parent => parent.EventSponsorId,
        sponsor => sponsor.EventSponsorId, 
        (parent, sponsor) => new { sponsor.InvitationCount })
    .Where(o => o.EventParentSponsors.ParentSponsorId).FirstOrDefault();
```

but I get this error

```
AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'EventParentSponsors'
and no extension method 'EventParentSponsors' accepting a first argument of type     'AnonymousType#1' could be found
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
totalTickets = context.EventParentSponsors.Join(context.EventSponsors, 
                                                x=>x.EventSponsorId,
                                                y=>y.EventSponsorId,
                                                (x,y) =>
                                                new 
                                                {
                                                    ID=x.ParentSponsorID , 
                                                    Count = x.InvitationCount 
                                                })
                                          .Where(x=>x.ID==parentId)
                                          .Select(x=>x.Count)
                                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ... the point being you've thrown away the parent sponsor ID in the .Join so it's not available to filter on in the .Where clause. You could also have moved the .Where clause before the .Join so that you're doing that filter first. (Incidentally your result is called `totalTickets` but this isn't a total - is that correct?)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to get `x.InvitationCount` not `x.Count` so this also giving an error.

Comment: @SMI he's renamed InvitationCount to just Count in the anonymous type in the middle - it should be the same thing? You could change that to `InvititationCount = x.InvitationCount` if you'd prefer.

Comment: @SMI I am sorry for replying late. Rup is correct. I have defined there an anonymous type, whose property Count corresponds to the InvitationCount. Is that clear?

Answer (score 2):

If you use LINQPad it will sort of show you what the method looks like in Lambda form:

```
totalTickets = context.EventParentSponsors
    .Join(context.EventSponsors, 
        parent => parent.EventSponsorId,
        sponsor => sponsor.EventSponsorId, 
        (parent, sponsor) => new { parent = parent, sponsor = sponsor })
    .Where(o => o.parent.EventParentSponsors.ParentSponsorId == parentId)
    .Select(o => o.sponsor.InvitationCount)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The key part you were missing is in your projection. When you use the query syntax, you are basically projecting both the parent and child elements:

```
(parent, sponsor) => new { parent = parent, sponsor = sponsor })
```

This is so you have full access to each side for future expressions.